# Wkhtmltopdf footer not rendering with position

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

With this in my html, the footer won't render in the pdf...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  footer{
background:#ccc;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
padding-top:50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <footer>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

It works when position is not specified...

To generate the pdf i'm using pdfkit with python:

```
pdfkit.from_file(content_url, 'out.pdf', {        
        '--footer-html': footer_url,
        '--footer-spacing':  '10'
    })
```

Here is the content I use in content_url

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<p> content </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help ?

Comment: give more code, we can't work only with this.

Comment: thanks for answer, edited

Comment: Have you tried a different positioning, like relative? And generating the pdf with another tool? It might be a bug with pdfkit, but I don't know anything about pdfkit. Is this all the html/css you have? if you omitted something it might be relevant...

Comment: Yes, positioning the footer doesn't work no matter the way I do it... I will try generating with wkhtmltopdf in CLI directly and keep you posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the body's height on the footer html to get it visible using positioning (like in other webpages).

Using the code below you get variabile height footer aligned to page bottom edge. **Note:** bottom margin must be specified when you call wkhtmltopdf, using **--margin-bottom** option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 1;
            font-size: 12pt;
            height: 20mm; /* set it to your bottom margin */
        }

        .footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="footer">test <b>html</b> footer<br/><i style="color:blue;">two lines</i></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt).

Answer (score 3):

Many people set margins at 0 to show the PDF page in the full paper.

This is a time when the problem is created for footer and header.

You need to set options in your command *** --margin-top 10 --margin-bottom 10 ***
or to set this in the configuration file for wkhtmltopd wrapper.

This is a configuration for snappyBundle (wkhtmltopdf wrapper library)

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     '%env(WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH)%'
        options:
          enable-javascript: true
          javascript-delay: 200
          no-stop-slow-scripts: true
          encoding: 'UTF-8'
          margin-top: 10
          margin-right: 0
          margin-bottom: 10
          margin-left: 0
```